# Can you use JQuery Datatables when you can't edit the source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

What is the easiest way to "inject" datatables.net code into a website so you can search and sort the contents? This is for an incredibly old application that is built in Java, and we don't have access to the backend code. Just looking for a workaround so some power users can search the page.

Can this be done by an end user using the console in the browser?

Comment: This could be done by creating a bookmarklet that injects all the resources needed then initializes the plugin. Then once working power users can be distributed the code and paste it into a new bookmark in browser. They would then need to click on browser bookmark to run the code every time they load the page

Comment: A user script certainly would do, using TamperMonkey which works on [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/). You would have to provide that script to your "power users".